# Concrete form bean for html select

Tags: struts

I have used `<html:select>` in one of my jsp pages with multiple selection. What varibles, for storing the selection, should i have in the form bean associated with this list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight from [the documentation](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-taglib/tagreference.html#html%3aselect):

> This tag operates in two modes, depending upon the state of the
>   multiple attribute, which affects the data type of the associated
>   property you should use:
>
> - multiple="true" IS NOT selected - The corresponding property should be a scalar value of any supported data type.
> - multiple="true" IS selected - The corresponding property **should be an array of any supported data type**.

(emphasis mine)